# How to serialise data structures with duplicate keys using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

#### The use-case

Assuming I have a source data structure that allows duplicate keys, something like a `Collection<Map.Entry<String, Object>>`, i.e. a hypothetical super type of `Map<String, Object>`. That type's string representation might look like this:

```
+--+--+-----+
|ID|ID|VALUE|
+--+--+-----+
| 1| 2|    a|
| 1| 3|    b|
+--+--+-----+
```

Now I would like to use Jackson to serialise the above source data structure to the most logical JSON representation, given that JSON also allows for duplicate keys, e.g. like this:

```json
[{
  "ID": 1,
  "ID": 2,
  "VALUE": "a"
}, {
  "ID": 1,
  "ID": 3,
  "VALUE": "b"
}]
```

#### A tempting, but unclean solution

A tempting approach here would be to let the source data structure just implement `Map<String, Object>`, violating the [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) contract, which reads:

> A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.

And just make sure `Map.entrySet()` produces the duplicate keys and their values, hoping that Jackson uses `Map.entrySet()` instead of `Map.keySet()` and then `Map.get()`. This feels very fishy, because:

- The `Map` contract is violated (as well as the `Set` contract for the sets returned by `Map.entrySet()` and `Map.keySet()`)
- By consequence, a few methods don't work as expected, including `Map.get()`, which can only produce one of the two conflicting values.
- The `Map` could be mutable, but not resizable, just like `Arrays.asList()`, which seems rather unprecedented and thus confusing (e.g. `remove()` and `clear()` don't work, `put()`, `putAll()` only work to mutate existing key/value pairs, `putIfAbsent()` is weird, because it doesn't work when a key is absent)
- While the above may be acceptable for the mere serialisation use-case, the source data structure is used for many other purposes, and users would now get a flawed `Map` representation of it, for all non-serialisation use-cases as well.

#### Hoping for a better solution

Is there a better out-of-the-box way to support duplicate keys when serialising data with Jackson, or do I have to implement a `JsonSerializer` for that purpose?

For context, the real-world source data structure is a jOOQ [`Record`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Record.html)